# Controller methods when submitting an AJAX request

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project that has a page with several forms on it. Most of the content on the page is rendered based on an initial form that a user submits. When a user updates information on that page I don't want the entire page to refresh I just need it to submit the form and stay on the page. I've tried to setup the form to submit with AJAX, but I don't know what to make the controller method return to accomplish this.

Form:

```
<div id="HeatNameDiv" title="Change Heat Name">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangeHeatName", "Home", new AjaxOptions(){UpdateTargetId = "HeatNameDiv"}))
{
    <section>
        Heat Name:<input type="text" name="heatName" value="@Html.ValueFor(x => x.heatname)" style ="width:100px"/>
        Change to:<input type="text" name="updatedHeat" value="" style="width: 100px" />
        <input type="submit" name="ChangeHeatName" value="Change" />
    </section>
}
```

Current Controller:

```
 public ActionResult ChangeHeatName(string heatName, string updatedHeat)
    {
        string user = User.Identity.Name;
        HomeModel H = new HomeModel();
        H.ChangeHeatName(heatName, updatedHeat, user);
        return Content("Index");
    }
```

Comment: you want to return a JsonResult, usually.

Comment: What would that look like if I'm just trying to stay on the same page though?

Comment: I'd use a jquery `$.post` command to submit your form data and return a JSON result.  If the result indicates success, tell your jQuery to do something, if failure, do something else.  I haven't found the `Ajax.BeginForm` very useful, but that is my personal prejudice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want refreshed.  Ajax.BeginForm expects an HTML fragment.  So you need a partial that represents the heatNameDiv that you want to replace after submit:

```
public ActionResult ChangeHeatName(string heatName, string updatedHeat)
    {
        string user = User.Identity.Name;
        HomeModel H = new HomeModel();
        H.ChangeHeatName(heatName, updatedHeat, user);
        return PartialView("NameOfPartialView", H);
    }
```

I agree with Jeremy because Ajax.BeginForm is less flexible.  I have tried hard to use it in the past, but the fact that it replaces the target element, instead of the innerHtml of the target, makes it difficult for many scenarios.

With `$.ajax` you can set `url: '@(Url.Action("MyActionReturningAPartialView"))'` and in the .success callback `function(response) { $('#heatNameDiv').innerHtml(response); }`

The action you call still returns a PartialView.